# How to deal with the date when import data from a xlsx file into R

Tags: r, datetime, format

The date data:2015-10-07 become 42284 when read in R from a xlsx file, how can I change it to the original one,2015-10-07?

Comment: You can use `as.Date(df1$date, origin = "1899-01-01")`

Comment: I think it should be `origin = "1899-12-30"`

Comment: @Marius you are right

Comment: I like to use janitor::excel_numeric_to_date()

Comment: Please show you R command for importing the excel file and include the name of the library called. Usually these "excel" packages return dates in the correct format, and there is no need to convert them after importation. So I suspect something is awry.